# Does aws charges for number of getObject calls to s3 or base on object size?

Tags: amazon-s3

We are using boto client to download objects from s3. But we have set the transfer config as:

```
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024*25, max_concurrency=10,
                        multipart_chunksize=1024*25, use_threads=True)
```

We in order to download 25GB of data we will request with 25KB of chunks per request.
So the total number of multipart request (getObject) calls to s3 will be 10000000 requests.
As per AWS pricing documentation, GET call cost us 0.0000004 USD per request.
Is the understanding correct that it will cost is 4 USD to download 25 GB with this approach of TransferConfig?

Comment: The cost involves both size and number of calls.   25gb / (1024 bytes * 25) = 1,048,576 total API requests.  (1,048,576 / 1000) * $0.0004 = $0.42 cost for the API calls, plus $0.023 per GB * 25 GB = $0.57 cost for the data transfer, so a total cost of $0.99 for this data retrieval.